# How to recover lost Microsoft Office 2013 Product Key after Windows 10 Reset PC

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, windows-registry, product-key

Although the Windows Lost Product Key question has been asked before, this is slightly different. 
I did 'Reset this PC' from Windows 10 Recovery without taking a backup of the system or files. All my files were safe but the Licensed Microsoft Office 2013 was removed. I have unfortunately misplaced the MS Office 2013 Student and Home product box. I have also checked with Windows Helpdesk if any of my emails are associated with the MS Office and the Microsoft Account; sadly, none are.

I read that that the 'Reset' cleans the registry and removes the apps. I am thinking of two ways to try and find the key

1. Use all the Free Key finders around then buy a paid one if they don't work
2. Use Recuva or a similar tool to try and recover the deleted old Windows Registry files

Has anyone faced a similar issue or can you think of an alternate way to try and get the Key?

Comment: [If  you have a valid proof of purchase Microsoft should be able to help you.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-your-Office-product-key-12a5763a-d45c-4685-8c95-a44500213759?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: Checked that with them too..since I had bought it from a retailer there is no email from Microsoft regd the same and they can't help me unless I there is an email/phone number tied to the Office software.

Answer (score 0):

### Has anyone faced a similar issue or can you think of an alternate way to try and get the Key?

No, I haven't wiped my computer without taking backup and haven't lost my product key either.

Performing data recovery to find registry, and try retrieve the product key sounds like worth a shot (*I would try this as my last resort*) but that could be an overkill when **you can simply find [proof of purchase](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-your-Office-product-key-12a5763a-d45c-4685-8c95-a44500213759?CorrelationId=c6df3187-1ed1-4cd1-bdf0-fc750763485e&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) and have Microsoft hand it over to you.**

[image]

Meaning, even if you don't have an email address or phone number tied to a product is not a problem as long as you can provide a valid proof of purchase

### What is a proof of purchase?

> A proof of purchase is an electronic or a physical document that
>   proves you purchased the licensed software from Microsoft or an
>   authorized reseller and that you paid for it. Usually, the proof of
>   purchase is a paid invoice or receipt, but it can also be a purchase
>   report from your large account reseller showing the title of the
>   software and the number of licenses you purchased.

[Source](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwifrKiUnbjNAhXCOY8KHYNsAGcQFgglMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2Ff%2F4%2F9%2Ff49c3745-3837-4ff9-9b73-91289dee7d3c%2Fsambrief-proof-of-license-for-microsoft-software.docx&usg=AFQjCNEA9MVkM3xHv6WEYKUwjBTN1jaReA&sig2=gB7MJJFAIIpB5WJSPB3SIA)

Comment: As I stated before @pun, I did check with Microsoft and their reply is in my reply to your comment on the above question. I can try pointing your highlighted statement to them.

Comment: @TejasMurthy I got your response. But read what does Proof of Purchase means and with that Microsoft should not have problems giving you a replacement key. It is not necessary to have a phone number or email tied to the product

Comment: Just checked with Microsoft on the phone, they said they will be able help in this regards only if it was purchased from a Microsoft Store.

Comment: @Tejas Try your luck with retailer

Comment: Tried that too @Pun..no cigar :(

Comment: @Tejas Go get some beer and DVD's to watch while you wait for the recovery to complete. Get some blessings too.